# Background Location Tracking iOS

Tags: ios, swift, geolocation, core-location

I need some help in tracking user location in background, suspended and killed state.

**Problem Statement**

I want to track user location after his consent in my App. I want to track user location in all the states Background, Suspended and Foreground. Till user has stopped it from the app. I am not able to track location in background and killed state but foreground is working fine.

I have also enabled below settings in my locationManager

```
locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
locationManager.showsBackgroundLocationIndicator = true


locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
```

***What I have tried till now is***

- Enabled background modes
- Location updates (checked)
- Background fetch (checked)
- Background processing (checked)
- Permission to Allow Always location access

Created a singleton for location tracking check the below code and calling this class on
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions - AppDelegate

```
   class EmployeeAttendanceTracker: NSObject,CLLocationManagerDelegate {


   static let shared = EmployeeAttendanceTracker()

private let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
private var lastLocationDate = Date()
static let LOCATION_INTERVAL = 1

var locationUpdate: (() -> Void)?

private override init() {
    super.init()
    setupLocationManager()
}

private func setupLocationManager() {
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.activityType = .other
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
    locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
    locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
    locationManager.showsBackgroundLocationIndicator = true
    
    
    if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
      locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    } else {
      locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }
}
  //    
//
//    // MARK: - CLLocationManagerDelegate
//    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization      status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        switch status {
        case .restricted:
            //showLocationPermissionAlert()
            Logger.s("Location access restricted.")
        case .denied:
            //showLocationPermissionAlert()
            Logger.s("User denied location access.")
        case .notDetermined:
           // showLocationPermissionAlert()
            Logger.s("Location access not determined.")
        case .authorizedAlways:
            if #available(iOS 9, *) {
                locationManager.requestLocation()
            } else {
                locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
                locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
            }
        default:
           // showLocationPermissionAlert()
            break
        }
    }


func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
guard let location = locations.last else { return }

Logger.s("User latitude: \(location.coordinate.latitude), longitude: \(location.coordinate.longitude)")
locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

let now = Date()
if isItTime(now: now as NSDate) {
    if shouldSendLocationToServer() {
        self.sendLocationToServer(location: location,completion: {
            self.locationUpdate?()
        })
    }else{
        self.locationUpdate?()
    }
    Logger.s(now)
    Logger.s(location)
}else{
    self.locationUpdate?()
}

  }
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You can’t access location when the app is killed and background is limited. You seem to have that covered.

Comment: Have you actually been granted the "always" permission? Until you are prompted by ios to update the location permission to always (or until you go into settings and update permissions directly) your app only has "provisional always" where it acts like "when in use".  You probably don't need all of that pre iOS 9 stuff . You should target iOS 13 as a minimum.

Comment: Why do you call `stopUpdatingLocation` in `didUpdateLocations`?  Don't do that. You will only get one update if you do that.  You need to keep the location updates running.

Comment: @Rob even if i do not force quit or even when i gracefuly go to another app it stops tracking location even if i lock my iphone

Comment: @Paulw11 Yes always permission is granted. I have removed stopUpdatingLocation in didUpdateLocations still the location is not updating

Comment: I grafted your code into the basic SwiftUI Core Data app that Xcode creates and it is recording locations every 10 seconds in the background.  Are you sure that the problem isn't related to how you process the location update rather than not getting the location updates?  I did change the object from being a singleton and remove the delegate pattern (A delegation pattern doesn't work well with singletons anyway)

Comment: can you share what you tried because in my case I am not able to track location once it goes to background or even if i lock my phone screen.

Comment: @Rob I have cross check Always Allow is enabled in my apps location setting that I am confirming.

Second your solution is working fine in my simulator but I want both startupdating location and significant change service because I want to track location even if app is killed or in backgroud even if user has not made any  significant change  in his location

Comment: Hi @Rob I am confirm the settings in by going in phone's seprarate settings. Can we carry forward our conversation to somewhere else? That would be more easy I guess if you ready?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256514/discussion-between-rob-and-android-geek).